# Check who has greatest number and give gift to them

Tags: java

I'm trying to find who are all having the greatest number and give the gift to persons who are having the greatest number.Consider if there are 4 persons.Get the input no as n1,n2,n3,n4.Then check which person have the greatest no and give gift to them.I just tried to find the greatest among 4 numbers.

```
int great=0;
if (n1 >= n2 && n1 >= n3 && n1>=n4)
    great=n1;
else if (n2 >= n1 && n2 >= n3 && n2>=n4)
    great=n2;
else if(n3>=n1 && n3>=n4)
    great=n3;
else
    great=n4;
```

if suppose 3 persons have same highest no then give the gift for 3 persons.Print the output as "Good you got a gift" along with the name of the persons who has greatest no with them.

Comment: Have a look at [`Math.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max(int,%20int)). You might want to consider writing an implementation of it which takes an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: *FYI:* Consider if there are 40 persons. You don't want to create 40 fields, `n1`, `n2`, `n3`, `n4`, `n5`, ..., `n39`, `n40`. Use an array or a `List`. That'll entirely change how you find the max, so you should change to array before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

first find the max value:

```
int[] all = new int[] { n1, n2, n3, n4 };
int max = -1;
for (int i=0; i<all.length; i++) {
    if (max < all[i) {
        max = all[i];
    }
}
```

then see who has the max value and print their index, name or whatever

```
for (int i=0; i<all.length; i++) {
    if (max == all[i) {
        System.out.println ("Good you got a gift " + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer[] a = {105, 30, 40, 110};
Arrays.sort(a, Collections.reverseOrder());
int great = a[0];
System.out.println("Good you got a gift: "+ great);
```

try this out

Comment: Nice example, except for the terrible naming. Why not `numbersFromUsers` instead of *a*, and `maximumNumber` instead of *great*. That would be *great* naming ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can work for you. I think you should go for a class Person which have name and number because at the end you want to show the name of the people with the highest number.

```
/**
 * Class representing each person
 */
public class Person{

    private final String name;
    private final Integer number;

    Person(String name, Integer number)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This is another class. Please create another file for it.

```
public class Main{
/**
 * This is the main method
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Person>all = new ArrayList<>();
    all.add(new Person("P1", 5));
    all.add(new Person("P2", 2));
    all.add(new Person("P3", 3));
    all.add(new Person("P4", 5));

    Integer max = findMaxNumber(all);

    List<Person> winners = findWinners(all, max);

    System.out.print("Good you got a gift: " + winners);
}

private static Integer findMaxNumber(List<Person> all) {
    Integer max = 0;

    for(Person onePerson : all)
    {
        Integer onePersonNumber = onePerson.getNumber();
        if(onePersonNumber > max)
        {
            max = onePersonNumber;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

private static List<Person> findWinners(List<Person> all, Integer max) {
    List<Person>winners = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Person onePerson : all)
    {
        if(onePerson.getNumber().equals(max))
        {
            winners.add(onePerson);
        }
    }
    return winners;
}

}//end of Main Class
```

### -------------------------------------------------------------------

This is a second solution. It is much like the first one just using lambda expressions.

```
/**
 * Class representing each person
 */
public class Person{

    private final String name;
    private final Integer number;

    Person(String name, Integer number)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This is another class. Please create another file for it.

```
public class Main{
/**
 * This is the main method
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Person>all = new ArrayList<>();
    all.add(new Person("P1", 5));
    all.add(new Person("P2", 2));
    all.add(new Person("P3", 5));
    all.add(new Person("P4", 5));

    Integer max = findMaxNumber(all);

    List<Person> winners = findWinners(all, max);

    System.out.print("Good you got a gift: " + winners);
}

private static Integer findMaxNumber(List<Person> all)
{
    /**
     * Map from Person to Integer (Person's number) and find the max number. 
     */
    OptionalInt maxNum = all.stream()
                            .mapToInt(p -> p.getNumber())
                            .max();
    return maxNum.getAsInt();
}

private static List<Person> findWinners(List<Person> all, Integer max) {
    /**
     * Filter the people that have the max number and collect them in the list
     */
    List<Person> winners = all.stream()
                              .filter(p -> p.getNumber().equals(max))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return winners;
}


}//end of Main Class
```